# Почему nginx не считывает ssl из заданого пути?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

Подскажите пожалуйста почему nginx не хочет считывать сертификаты и ключи к ним из заданных источников?

Пример когда не считывается адрес:

/etc/letsencrypt/live/<имя сайта>/fullchain.pem;

/etc/letsencrypt/live/<имя сайта>/privkey.pem;

а считывает только из

/etc/ssl/certs/<имя файла>

/etc/ssl/private/<имя файла>

То есть если переместить сертификат и ключи из первого примера во второй то все работает

Comment: Потому что пути прибиты при компиляции?

Comment: Да пути задались сами, я как бы понимаю что можно сделать костыль и чтоб при обновление сертификата делалось копирование сертификата и ключа в нужное место, но хотелось бы понять почему так происходит что nginx не хочет считывать из заданного мной места

Comment: `server { ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<имя сайта>/fullchain.pem; }`
и
`systemctl restart nginx`

Answer (score 1):

ковыряйте прова доступа.

для проверки:

> chmod -R 777 /etc/letsencrypt/live/

Если заработает, разбирайтесь более детально

Comment: Не помогло к сожалению

Comment: А если я в файле конфига который находиться тут /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/site.conf задам другие пути хранения. как сделать обновление конфига и будет ли это работать?